# Long time reloading pages because weblogic 12.2.1.3.0 triggers recompiling jsp every page acces

Tags: jsp, weblogic, apache-tiles

I use weblogic 12.2.1.3.0 and EVERY TIME (not only the first time) I access a web page I wait for 2 minutes for it to render cause weblogic apparently recompiles all the jsps that it contains. Every page is made up of fragments using apache tiles 3.0 using definitions like these:

```
<definition name="includeTemplate" template="/WEB-INF/jsp/templates/includeTemplate.jsp">
  <put-attribute name="content" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp"/>
  <put-attribute name="headContent" value=""/>
  <put-list-attribute name="dialogs">
    <add-attribute value="messageDialogDef"/>
    <add-attribute value="validationDialogDef"/>
    <add-attribute value="detailDialogDef"/>
  </put-list-attribute>
</definition>
```

Weblogic throws lots of these messages in its log files:

```
<BEA-101360> <Recompiling JSP [ServletContext@1759767545[app:app-ear_ear module:/app path:null spec-version:3.1]], resource [/WEB-INF/jsp/templates/list/menu.jsp], because it is stale.>
```

I also use spring (mvc) 4.3.21

Any idea what is going on and how to avoid **only** the **useless** recompilings?

Comment: log messages are missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug. There is a patch for WLS 12.2.1.3.0

Comment: I was using a version downloaded in dec 2018, but downloading NOW the current version from oracle site I see it was last updated on 21.08.2017 so I guess they didn't apply the patch on the main version, which means they don't care about developers anymore?

Comment: It's their patch policy. i.e.: https://blogs.oracle.com/fusionmiddlewaresupport/july-2019-oracle-weblogic-server-patch-set-update-have-been-released

Comment: Anyway, if you recompile the war before deploying it, still do you get the "stale" message ?

Comment: Yes I get the stale all the time, even after the first acces. Also, I get the long access time EVERY access to the pages. the only time I get access time in 2s to the page is when i set -1 to: servlet-reload-check-secs, resource-reload-check-secs, page-check-seconds.

Comment: Ok. then you need to apply the patch.

Comment: Downloaded the new weblogic version 12.2.1.4 and it works as expected now

Comment: great ! the bug declared that in that version will be solved